# How to get a value of a input field in to array of multiple Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a form with multiple input field, I need to get value of that form and pass into JSON object as shown below. each of the field will have object in the array. How Do I get all multiple field to pass as Array of Object.(form will allow to add multiple field)

I'm using JavaScript and jQuery to get all Value.

```
<div class="info">
<div class="field">
  <label> field 1 </label>
  <input placeholder="Name" class="name" type="text">
  <input placeholder="email"   class="email" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Address"  class="address" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label> field 2</label>
  <input placeholder="Name"  class="name" type="text">
  <input placeholder="email"  class="email" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Address"  class="address" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label> field 3 </label>
   <input placeholder="Name"  class="name" type="text">
  <input placeholder="email"   class="email" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Address"  class="address" type="text">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label> field 4 </label>
  <input placeholder="Name"  class="name" type="text">
  <input placeholder="email"  class="email" type="text">
  <input placeholder="Address"  class="address" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```

On click event will get the form value and The final JSON object will look like,

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "Name": "string 1",
      "email": "this",
      "Address": "that"
    },
    {
      "Name": "string 2",
      "email": "this",
      "Address": "that"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to getting value from each of the input in different field.

```
  var nameInput = document.getElementsByClassName("name"),

      names = [].map.call(nameInput, function(input) {
        return input.value;
      });
```

But How do I add email and address field in object and map into array,

Comment: There is no code... Show what you tryed.

Comment: I have edited the question,  I'm getting single field value by array.map

Comment: but there is no such class named `name` have you tried getting the values from `id tag` ?

Comment: oh sorry , I forgot to add class in HTML, I have added now

Comment: By the way, [it's bad UI](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/) to label a text field using only a placeholder. It's better to have a text label that is always visible, so users can double-check whether they typed the information in the correct field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. The variable `formData` has the structure you want.

This code assumes that the key `"info"` is always the same, so it always looks within `.info`.

```js
var fieldsValues = [];

$(".info .field").each(function(index, field) {
  var fieldData = {};
  $(field).find("input").each(function(index, input) {
    fieldData[input.placeholder] = input.value;
  });

  fieldsValues.push(fieldData);
});

var formData = {info: fieldsValues};
console.log(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info">
  <div class="field">
    <label> field 1 </label>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="name" type="text" value="some name 1">
    <input placeholder="email" class="email" type="text" value="some email 1">
    <input placeholder="Address" class="address" type="text" value="some address 1">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label> field 2</label>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="email" class="email" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Address" class="address" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label> field 3 </label>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="email" class="email" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Address" class="address" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label> field 4 </label>
    <input placeholder="Name" class="name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="email" class="email" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Address" class="address" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    var result = {"info":[]};
    $(".info .field").each(function () {
        var info = {};
        $(this).children("input").each(function () {
            eval("info." + $(this).attr("placeholder") + "='" + $(this).val()+"'");
        });
        result.info.push(info);
    });
```

Comment: `eval` [should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!) when possible. To set the property of an object where the property name is in a variable, you can use `obj[name] = val`, or `info[$(this).attr("placeholder")] = $(this).val()` in this case. The version with `eval` could break if `$(this).val()` had special characters like `"` or ``\`` in it.